# How to generate the query to clone an existing table

Tags: cassandra

I use the community edition of Cassandra (not DSE). Earlier I used to use a tool called descanter. when I click "clone" in descanter on an existing table. it used to give me the CQL necessary to re-create the existing table.

Now on my new MacOS (High Sierra) the devcenter tool is broken. I searched on the forums and found that DataStax has no intention of maintaining the tool.

So I am now using the command line CQLSH. Now in CQLSH if I have an existing table. How to generate the query to clone an existing table?

I only need the table structure. I don't need any data.

I cannot physically login to the Cassandra server. So everything needs to be done by connecting to Cassandra remotely using CQLSH.

Comment: You can look to new version of DataStax Studio 6.0 that is available as part of EAP (Early Access Program) & that has support for CQL inside: https://academy.datastax.com/eap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DESCRIBE command](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshDescribe.html) should help you